# How to use the pretrained model in an application?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, lstm

I dont understand how to use the trained model.

For example I trained the model using the code from https://towardsdatascience.com/what-is-a-recurrent-neural-network-and-implementation-of-simplernn-gru-and-lstm-models-in-keras-f7247e97c405.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

imdb, info = tfds.load("imdb_reviews",with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
train_data, test_data = imdb['train'], imdb['test']
training_sentences = []
training_labels = []
testing_sentences = []
testing_labels = []
for s,l in train_data:
    training_sentences.append(str(s.numpy()))
    training_labels.append(l.numpy())
for s,l in test_data:
    testing_sentences.append(str(s.numpy()))
    testing_labels.append(l.numpy())

training_labels_final = np.array(training_labels)
testing_labels_final = np.array(testing_labels)

vocab_size = 10000
embedding_dim=16
max_length = 120
trunc_type= 'post'
oov_tok="<OOV>"

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = vocab_size, oov_token=oov_tok)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(training_sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
word_index

sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(training_sentences)
padded = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=max_length, 
                       truncating = trunc_type)
testing_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(testing_sentences)
testing_padded = pad_sequences(testing_sequences, maxlen=max_length)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim,
                             input_length=max_length),
    tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(32),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

num_epochs=30
history=model.fit(padded, training_labels_final, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data = (testing_padded, testing_labels_final))
```

It is all from this link.

Then I added the last line of code

```
model.save('name.model')
```

Then I open the new script where I want to use this model. I suggests that I will put a sentence ("He is a bad cat.") and I will get 0 or 1 depending wether it represents good sentiment or bad sentiment (I think I must get 0).

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras 
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

model=tf.keras.models.load_model('name.model')

print(model.output_shape)

prediction=model.predict(["He is a bad cat."])
print(prediction)
```

And I get error.

QUESTION 1: In which format I must put this sentance? If I give this model to my friend how does he know in which format he must put the sentence to this model?

QUESTION 2: I noticed that the output will have (None,1) format. But I hoped to see one number (0 or 1) but not strange vector. What is going and how to get 0 or 1?

Comment: The model needs the test sentence to be preprocessed exactly like the training data (tokenized and padded).

Comment: @Erwan Thanks! But I dont understand how. For tokenization I need word indexes. Before training I got word indexes and tokenized sentences (and it depends on this word indexes if I understand correct). Now I want to use my trained model. How can I tokenize a new sentence without my  word indexes? So I must repeat all steps again (including crearing word indexes)? So if it is correct then I must give this word index list with the model to my friend?

Comment: The problem is that I'm not familiar with Keras so I don't know how to do it technically, hopefully somebody will give you a full answer. What is sure is that there must be a way to save either the tokenizer itself or the training vocabulary (with indexes), so that it can be loaded later and applied to a new text. This is the way to do it. Btw it can happen that some test words are not in the training vocabulary, the simple method is to ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you make predictions you have to convert your text to input format.

For example, to make a prediction of "He is a bad cat." you have to tokenize the sentence.

```
#tokenizing the prediction data
sentence=['He is a bad cat.']
sequences=tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentence)
```

Then you have to add padding to it

```
#padding the tokenized sentence
padded=pad_sequences(sequences,maxlen=max_length,truncating=trunc_type)
```

Then you can make predictions on the padded sequence

```
model1.predict(padded) #output: array([[0.00079787]], dtype=float32)
```

The output will be a float not exactly 0 or 1 because the model will give the value based on the given sentence close to the negative or positive side on the embedding.

For more details please refer to this working [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/b8849beee02d366748e1c18e8826948d). Thank You.